# Prepare a sampling plan using probability sampling techniques

Tags: self-study, sampling, experiment-design

Yesterday  I have done my MBA exam, I have faced a question in Probability, I will put the questions please answer anyone knows?

> A research agency is planning to conduct a survey regarding "Students
>   Attitude towards facebook". They want to collect data from engineering
>   students across Tamilnadu. The sample size is 1000. Prepare a Sampling
>   Plan using Probability Sampling Techniques.

Comment: What consitutes a reasonable sampling plan depends on a number of factors... have you checked the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(statistics)) on sampling?